# how to change the default field value from another model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

How can I change the status field default value of `formdownload` model record to true when a value is picked in `form_serial_no_id` Many2one field of `plot.allocate` model?

I have written a method to override odoo create function of the `PlotAllocation` model but it's still not changing the value of status field to true. Instead, it goes to the override function of create method in the parent class(plot.allocate). Anytime I save record, control goes to the create function of the parent method and ignore the create function of class `PlotAllocation` that inherit the `plot.allocate` model. How can I fix this?

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api


class CompanyName(models.Model):
    _name = 'companyname'
    _rec_name = 'company_name'

    company_name = fields.Char(string="Company Name", required=True)
    company_short_code = fields.Char(string="Company short code", required=True)


class FormDownload(models.Model):
    _name = 'formdownload'
    _rec_name = 'form_serial_no'

    name = fields.Many2one('companyname', string="Company Name", ondelete='cascade',
                           required=True)
    form_serial_no = fields.Char(string="Form Serial No", readonly=True)
    status = fields.Boolean(string="Status", default=False)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        serial_no = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('formdownload.form_serial_no')
        code = self.env['companyname'].browse(vals['name']).company_short_code

        # capitalize company short code values
        code = code.upper()

        # merge code and serial number
        vals['form_serial_no'] = code + serial_no
        return super(FormDownload, self).create(vals)


class PlotAllocation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'plot.allocate'

    form_serial_no_id = fields.Many2one('formdownload',
                                        domain=[('status', '=', False)],
                                        ondelete='cascade', string="Form Serial No")

    def create(self, vals):
        form_id = vals['form_serial_no_id']
        form_obj = self.env['formdownload'].browse(vals['status'])

        if form_id:
            form_obj.write({'status': True})

        return super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
```

Here is the create override function of the parent class

```py
class plot_allocate(osv.osv):
    _name = 'plot.allocate'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']    

def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        offer_dt = vals.get('offer_dt')
        offer_price = vals.get('offer_price')
        plot_no = vals.get('plot_no')
        payment_plan = vals.get('payment_plan')
        # generate and store the offer letter reference number
        vals['offer_letter_reference_number'] = self.pool.get(
            'ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'offer_letter_reference_number')
        # override creation method to prevent creation of duplicate plots
        if plot_no:
            plot_no_duplicate = self.search(
                cr, uid, [('plot_no', '=', plot_no)])
            if plot_no_duplicate:
                raise osv.except_osv(
                    _('Duplicate!'),
                    _('Plot No is allocated or is open for allocation already'))
        # change status of unallocated plots to allocated in unit_master
        unit_master = self.pool.get('unit.master').browse(cr, uid, plot_no)
        # change corresponding plot in unit_master to allocated
        unit_master.write({'status': 'allocated'})
        project_and_plot_id = super(
            plot_allocate, self).create(
            cr, uid, vals, context=context)
        plot = self.browse(cr, uid, project_and_plot_id, context=context)
        if payment_plan:
            self.calc_payment_plan(cr, uid, plot, offer_dt, payment_plan)
        return project_and_plot_id
```

Comment: You are comparing boolean with integer, does it make sense ?  `if vals['form_serial_no_id'] == status:`

Comment: what is vals['name'] here?

Comment: which version of odoo you are using in this?

Comment: @bhuro, i use odoo 8

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
@api.model   
def create(self, vals):
    status = self.env['formdownload'].browse(vals['form_serial_no_id'])         
    if self.form_serial_no_id.id == status.status:
        status.write({'status': True})     
    return super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but nothing changes. It's still the same thing.

Comment: I realized that there is an override function of create method in the parent class(plot.allocate), so anytime i save record, control goes to the create function of the parent method and ignore the create function of class "PlotAllocation" that inherit the plot.allocate model. How can i fix this?

Comment: matching return super(class_inherit_name, self).create(vals), because it will be overwrite default method.

Comment: Thanks rinaldi, the problem is program flow is not entering into the create function at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    form_id = vals['form_serial_no_id'].id
    form_obj = self.env['formdownload'].browse([form_id])

    if your condition:
        form_obj.write({'status':True})

    return super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's still the same thing. Nothing happened

Comment: If you tell me up to where you reached, it will be helpful to help

Comment: i just discovered now that there is an override function of create method in the parent class(plot.allocate), so anytime i save record, control goes to the create function of the parent method and ignore the create function of class "PlotAllocation" that inherit the plot.allocate model. how can i fix this? I have edited the question and added the create function in the parent class for you to see.

Comment: If you override create function, then you should mandatory call the superclass create function. But in plot_allocation class, you failed to call it

Comment: plot_allocate class is the superclass, whatever i have to do have to be in PlotAllocation class....so, i dont think i understand what you are saying!

Comment: Your plot_allocate class is inheriting osv.osv model. This model has default create function provided by odoo. So if you add a create function you actually overriding the create function of osv.osv

Comment: Moreover you are mixing odoo V7 and V8

Comment: mixing V7 and V8 was as a result of code editing, it was not on purpose, i have edited the question again.

Comment: there is a super call in the function!

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and it work just fine :

```py
@api.model
 def create(self, vals):
        rec_id = super(PlotAllocation, self).create(vals)
        if rec_id.form_serial_no_id :
            # raise exceptions.ValidationError('Your code is here should make the status of companyname to true')
            # print 'Your code is here should make the status of companyname to true'
            rec_id.form_serial_no_id.status = True
        return rec_id
```

Comment: add added to commented line if you can see the print in console uncomment the print line else uncomment the raise line just to see if the code is really colling your create method because i tried this and it work just fine.

Comment: No, i didnt get any message.

Comment: Did you put the mode'in init.py file pjt the raise exception in the firt line of create method and check the init file of hour module one by one you must import. What i mean check you structure you are doing some thing wrong

Comment: Put raise exception in the first line if you don't get the message than check the structure the indentation of your file the code shoud work keep checking untill hou find what you did wrong

Comment: I did according to what you said and i realized that there is an override function of create method in the parent class(plot.allocate), so anytime i save record, control goes to the create function of the parent method and ignore the create function of class "PlotAllocation" that inherit the plot.allocate model. How can i fix this?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the create function in the parent class for you to see.